# How to insert OOXML into locked Content Control in native and Online Word?

Tags: office-js, word-addins

I am developing a Word add-in that inserts OOXML into locked content controls (i.e. both `cannotDelete` and `cannotEdit` flags are set), and am experiencing issues with the results between native and Online Word.  In native Word, the `cannotEdit` flag is honored, so `ContentControl.insertOoxml` will fail unless I first disable the flag, regardless of whether or not I use `start` or `replace` as the second parameter.

However, in Word Online, using `start` as the second parameter ignores both flags (succeeding regardless of their value) and replaces any current content with the inserted OOXML instead of prepending it.  When `replace` is used, the end result is as expected, but the `cannotDelete` flag controls whether or not the call succeeds rather than `cannotEdit`.

The end result is that I cannot readily prepend OOXML within a content control, because Word Online overwrites any current content, and I must disable both flags when doing an actual replace because `cannotEdit` is honored by native Word and `cannotDelete` is honored by Word Online.

Here is a simple script to demonstrate the issue:

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    return Word.run(function (context) {

        var contentControls = context.document.contentControls;
        context.load(contentControls, 'id');

        return context.sync().then(function () {

            var control = contentControls.items[0];

            //control.cannotDelete = false;
            //control.cannotEdit = false;

            // Use 'start' or 'replace' as a second parameter to notice varying behavior in Word Online
            control.insertOoxml("<pkg:package xmlns:pkg='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage'><pkg:part pkg:name='/_rels/.rels' pkg:contentType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml' pkg:padding='512'><pkg:xmlData><Relationships xmlns='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships'><Relationship Id='rId1' Type='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument' Target='word/document.xml'/></Relationships></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name='/word/document.xml' pkg:contentType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml'><pkg:xmlData><w:document xmlns:w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main' ><w:body><w:p><w:pPr><w:spacing w:before='360' w:after='0' w:line='480' w:lineRule='auto'/><w:rPr><w:color w:val='70AD47' w:themeColor='accent6'/><w:sz w:val='28'/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:color w:val='70AD47' w:themeColor='accent6'/><w:sz w:val='28'/></w:rPr><w:t>This text has formatting directly applied to achieve its font size, color, line spacing, and paragraph spacing.</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:body></w:document></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part></pkg:package>", "start");

            //control.cannotDelete = true;
            //control.cannotEdit = true;

            return context.sync();
        });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
};
```

I also created a [simple document](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AoSTP7z7S0tYgie78NiXp17LBRyw) for testing, although it is nothing more than a locked, rich text content control with some content.

As is, the script will fail in native Word, because the `cannotEdit` flag is not disabled first, but will succeed in Word Online and the test text will be replaced (even though `start` is used).  Using `replace` instead of `start` and un-commenting the lines that set `control.cannotEdit`, will cause it to succeed in native Word, but fail in Word Online.  In order to get it to succeed in both environments when `replace` is used, the `control.cannotDelete` lines must be un-commented as well.

Is this expected behavior?  What is the recommended way to use `ContentControl.insertOoxml` in both Online and native environments?